# Check if image url is valid

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hello i'm making a Discord bot in Python. I'm making a meme command that gets a random submission from a subreddit. Well there is a little problem with it. When the submission is a video or an unavailble format for Discord, embed can't load the content. So i need to check for submissions format and when it's an unavailble format then the function should be recalled or something like that. I couldn't figure out myself so im asking for help. Here is the code:

```
@client.command()
async def meme(ctx):
    if not hasattr(client, 'nextMeme'):
        client.nextMeme = await getMeme()

    title, url, img_url, upvotes, comments = client.nextMeme

    embedVar = discord.Embed(title=title, url=url, color=discord.Color.random())
    embedVar.set_image(url=img_url)
    embedVar.set_footer(text=f" {upvotes} |  {comments}")

    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

    client.nextMeme = await getMeme()

async def getMeme():
    meme_subreddits = ['dankmemes', 'memes', 'jaharia', 'videoyun']
    subreddit = await reddit.subreddit(random.choice(meme_subreddits))
    all_subs = []

    top = subreddit.top(limit = 52)

    async for submission in top:
        all_subs.append(submission)
    
    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)

    img_url = random_sub.url
    title = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.shortlink
    upvotes = random_sub.score
    comments = random_sub.num_comments
    
    return title, url, img_url, upvotes, comments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the image url you're getting ends with a supported file extension, with something like this:

```
if img_url.endswith(('.jpg', '.png', '.gif', '.jpeg')):
```

If you wanna try until you get a valid one, just put it in a while loop, something like this should work? I cant test it right now, sorry

```
img_url = ''
while not img_url.endswith(('.jpg', '.png', '.gif', '.jpeg')):
    title, url, img_url, upvotes, comments = client.nextMeme
#rest of your code
```

You can obviously add more file extensions, these were just the ones I could come up with quickly. Hope this helps you at least a little bit